# Can a private on-premise network access GAE Flex via Cloud VPN?

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I was wondering if a site-to-site VPN setup like the one in this diagram is possible:

[image]

From the diagram, I could access the GAE Flex instance's internal IP that are launched in the VPC from the on-premise server, but I don't think I could invoke a *.appspot.com URL without needing to go outside of the tunnel, correct?

The on-premise network can only whitelist IP ranges for external HTTPS access but it seems like GAE can't support such a configuration?

Is this kind of setup only possible by setting up a GCE reverse proxy? If that's the case, would I just be better off deploying my application as a Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the specific set-up you are looking for, but you might like to look into two alternatives:

- [App Engine Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/creating-firewalls)
- [Identity Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview)

These both allow you to limit and control access to your GAE App. This, combined with SSL, might provide sufficient security that you don't need your on-prem to GAE traffic to go through the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

In Google App Engine Flex environment is possible to configure more scenarios than the standard GAE. For the first question you can use a [dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/how-requests-are-routed) file for rerouting the request inside your network configuration.

For use the request inside your VPN tunnel you need to add the network configuration to your [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#network_settings) file.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-gcp-apis-from-an-external-network) are some examples for use GCP Apis from on-premise network and a similar question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37137914/is-it-possible-to-use-google-app-engine-with-google-cloud-vpn).

If with these options you can not obtain the desired configuration, using a Kubernetes cluster may be an option.